# Why couldn't the Ministry of Magic use Veritaserum to question Winky about Barty Crouch Jr.'s Testimony?

Tags: harry-potter, dementors, house-elves, potions, barty-crouch-jr

Since Winky was present at the testimony of Bartemius Crouch Jr. (in the Defense Against the Dark Arts office), she would have remembered it. In addition, she could confirm that what he was saying was true. Why did McGonagall and Dumbledore give up on finding evidence for Crouch's testimony after he was administered the Dementor's Kiss?

In addition to confirming Crouch's testimony with her own, she could also provide her memories that would be visible through use of a Pensieve, and along with those of Snape, Dumbledore, McGonagall, and Harry, this would have made for VERY convincing evidence. In addition, who is to say that Crouch lost his memory after the Dementor's Kiss? Do dementors suck out memories in addition to the soul?

Comment: Remember, Fudge had zero interest in the truth of Voldemort's return. Any evidence that Dumbledore provided would have been chalked up to Fudge's Dumbledore conspiracy / refusal to believe

Comment: I suspect they wouldn't hold much faith in the testimony of a house elf anyway. Kind of how Lupin's testimony wouldn't be respected since he is a werewolf and holds little respect. Most wizards don't respect House Elves.

Answer (score 0):

Veritaserum and Pensieve memories are not perfect. If a person was obliviated and false-memory charmed, then the facts admitted under Veritaserum would be compromised. Also, a proficient Occlumens may have the strength to resist the effects of Veritaserum.